# How to get the views of other items than clicked item in ListView OnItemClickListener?

Tags: android, view, android-listview, nullpointerexception, onitemclicklistener

I am facing trouble in getting the other views than the clicked item view on clicking any of the listview items. I need to hide a view from each of the list item view, other than the clicked item view.

The code below is working fine for less items 4 or 5, that are visible at a time, but creating problem (crashing with the force close - NullPointerException on initialization of panel1) in case I am having multiple items, that are occupying more than screen size.

```
 for(int count = 0; count<listAdapter.getCount(); count++)

    {

     if(arg2!=count) 

       {

     int visiblePosition = jobList.getFirstVisiblePosition();

     View v = jobList.getChildAt(count - visiblePosition);



            panel1 = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.panel1);

    panel1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    }
```

I just replaced initialization of view in my above code

from

```
      View v = jobList.getChildAt(count - visiblePosition);
```

to

```
      View v = jobList.getChildAt(count);
```

But still, the problem is same, i.e, **I am receiving NPE on the view, in case, I do have more items than the currently visible items**. I guess this is because the wrong condition in my for loop  **count < listAdapter.getCount()**, I guess this must be changed to something else, in order to get out of this trouble.

Please suggest, what should be the changed in for loop (initialization / condition)?

Comment: can u post the adapter class ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will get `NullPointerException` because you are trying to access view which doesn't exists.

**View doesn't exists? Why?**

why because ListView recycle the views for the performance reasons. So it will allocate memory for the visible items in the list.
  i.e for example if you list has 100 items and you can see 10 items at a time, then listview will allocate memory for 10 views only, Remain views will be allocated when they are visible i.e when you scroll listview to identify items.

**What you need to do?**

Keep track of each item and its visibility in ArrayList and then set visibility of selected item to VISIBLE and rest to gone

Sorry I can't code for you, but I'll provide alternate simple solution for you

Try this simple way

Example:

Take a View like this in your Activity

```
View v;
```

And initialize it in `onCreate`

```
v=new View();
```

and in your listview onItemClick

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long arg3) {
      v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      v=view;
      view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

**Edit:**

Take a Variable in your Adapter like this

```
 int visibility=View.VISIBLE;
```

And

set the visibility of items in your to

```
 view.setVisibility(visibility);
```

And then in the `onItemClick` do like this

you can access your visibility field in Activity with Adapter instance so

```
adapter.visibility=View.GONE;
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

// second parameter in onItemClick

Comment: May you please elaborate the way of doing this?

Comment: My requirement is to hide the views existing in list items, so, I need to hide each and every view corresponding to the list items position. How can I do that?

Comment: I also tried using listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() and listView.invalidate() for refreshing the list in onItemClick before making the desired (clicked) view visible, but none of them worked as per my requirement.

Comment: @NarendraDroidWorm What is your requirement? Have you tried what I have posted above? What is the output you are expecting? Above solution should work, as I have posted that After having a try

Comment: No, I haven't tried it yet, I just commented together with your edit. My requirement is just to refresh the list, before performing the visibility operations.

Comment: You can get all the items which are  visible on screen .But to get all other views you have to get this adapter and return position in the main activity .

Comment: @Harsh Getting the views of all the visible items will help me out (I guess), and on clicking any of the list item, I want to make views of all the visible items to be hidden at first. Plz may you suggest how can I get the views of all the visible items.

Comment: @NarendraDroidWorm `count - visiblePosition` will also be wrong because if count=100 and you can see only 10, you will get 100-10=90, so condition will fail again.

Comment: My problems got solved partially by replacing count<listAdapter.getCount() to count<jobList.getLastVisiblePosition()

Comment: Now, the crash occurs after I scroll and clicking any item after that. Then I get NPE.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is get the position of the clicked item. Run a for loop from 0 to getChildCount() and match each position with the clicked position. If it matches do nothing in the else part do view.setVisibility(View.Invisible). It will work I think and I hope your problem gets solved.....

Got the Solution 
Here is your onItemCLickListener

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            clickArrayList.clear();
            Toast.makeText(
                    ViewActivity.this,
                    "First Name: "
                            + studentArrayList.get(
                                    (int) listView.getAdapter().getItemId(
                                            arg2)).getFirstName() + "\n"
                            + "Last Name: "
                            + studentArrayList.get(arg2).getLastName(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            for (int i = 0; i < listView.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {
                if (arg2 == i) {

                } else {

                    clickArrayList.add(arg2);
                }

            }
            listView.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(ViewActivity.this,
                    studentArrayList, clickArrayList));



        }
    });
```

and in the getview method in your custom adapter do this just before returning your convert view....

```
    for (int i = 0; i < clicked.size(); i++) {
        Log.d("tag", "Position.... " + clicked.get(i));
        if (!(clicked.get(i) == arg0)) {
            holder.FirstnameText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.lastNameText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.FirstnameText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.lastNameText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please let me know, how may I get the views in else part?

Comment: I have no problem in if part (where the position matches), only the else part is bothering me much, as I am unable to get the corresponding views of the items, which are not clicked.

Comment: I think you are doing it in your ListItem.setOnItemClickListener ? If yes then you have an attribute as view so in the else part set that view as view.setvisibility(View.Invisible) thats it.

Comment: But, that view will be the clicked item view, in which I am really not interested. I am just interested in the other views, i.e, the rest of the views, which I ddn't click.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < listView.getChildCount(); i++) {
     if (arg2 == i) {
     } else {
      listView.getChildAt(i).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
     }

     listView.getChildAt(arg2).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }  ---------- Check this code its working for me I hope it works for you too.

Comment: Thats working only in the case, when I do have less items (say 3 or 4 items) in the listview. But, in case of more items where I do need to scroll,then, after the scroll, it works improperly.

Comment: Got the solution.... Check My updates answer... If any problem please feel free to ask.....

Answer (score 0):

When you write an item click listener in the main activity, it gives you three parameters:

- the parent view
- current view
- position

From within the parent view, you can get all the views present. You can hide the other views and notify them to adapter via the `notifyDataSetChanged` method. You can also maintain the state of the view, whether it is visible from database.